# Lego 88012 hub socket type

Tags: technic, powered-up, connections

The LEGO Technic hub 88012 has 4 sockets. Can anyone tell me what the socket types are?

I have tried to find out via LEGO Support and they directed me to this site.

I have searched the internet and been unsuccessful.

I want to use the hub to build MOC, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a photo of the hub:

[image: 88012 hub]

It includes four Powered Up ports. These are compatible with peripherals (motors, sensors, lights, etc) from the lines branded as Powered Up, Control+, Boost, Robot Inventor, Wedo 2.0, and SPIKE.

If you are hoping to make custom electronics for this, the port itself uses a proprietary connector that is not widely available. You may be able to [find connectors online, or build something that might work](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/are-there-powered-up-compatible-connectors-available).